# Big O Complexity of Recursive function in a Loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, depth-first-search

I came across a Solution to a Leetcode problem of finding increasing subsequences. I think the solution has a complexity of O(N!) and might not scale for large arrays.

Can you please elaborate on how you calculated complexity for this ?

```
public class IncreasingSubsequences {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] a = new int[]{4, 6, 7, 8};
        findSubsequences(a);
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> findSubsequences(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<>();
        helper(new LinkedList<Integer>(), 0, nums, res);
        return res;
    }

    // [4, 6, 7, 7]
    private static void helper(LinkedList<Integer> list, int index, int[] nums, List<List<Integer>> res) {

        if (list.size() > 1){
            res.add(new LinkedList<Integer>(list));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
        }

        Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = index; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (used.contains(nums[i]))
                continue;
            if (list.size() == 0 || nums[i] >= list.peekLast()) {
                used.add(nums[i]);
                list.add(nums[i]);
                helper(list, i + 1, nums, res);
                System.out.println("Will remove" + list.get(list.size() - 1));
                list.remove(list.size() - 1);
                //System.out.println(">>" + Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Time and memory complexity is almost O(N!), as you suspected. More precisely, additional memory is O(N*2<sup>N</sup>), and time is O(M*2<sup>N</sup>). Where M is the length of `nums`, the original list, and N is the number of unique values in it (s.t. N<=M).

The complexity expression is easy to derive after you realize that the recursive function is called once for each value in the resulting list. When the input `nums` contains items in increasing order, the resulting list contains all possible subsets of `nums` values. In effect, the program prints and returns the power set of the original set. If there are also non-increasing items, then the result may be smaller but not larger.

If the original set contains N (unique) values, in ascending order of `nums`, then the power set contains 2<sup>N</sup> unique sets. This is also the length of the resulting list, and the number of calls to the recursive function.

It is possible to show that each element in the original set appears exactly in half of the subsets (assuming ascending order). This means that if we write all the 2<sup>N</sup> lists of the result (which represent all the subsets), and concatenate them, each item will appear 2<sup>N</sup>/2 times. Since there are N unique values, then the length of the concatenate list will be 2<sup>N</sup>*N/2, which is O(N*2<sup>N</sup>).

We can safely ignored the length of the top-level list, that contains all the subsets, since it's shorter than all lists concatenated together. So finally, the additional space complexity is O(N*2<sup>N</sup>). This is also the complexity of printout (its length). If M>N then, in the worst case, all repeated items come at the end. This causes all recursive to calls have to execute additional M-N operations at the end of each call. Since there are 2<sup>N</sup> calls, then the time complexity becomes O(N*2<sup>N</sup>)+
O((M-N)*2<sup>N</sup>) = O(M*2<sup>N</sup>).

Note that time complexity is almost optimal, since the time complexity can't be lower than the additional-memory complexity. Though, it's impossible to scale slightly better than that. The only inefficient spot is handling non-unique values. If the repeating values are removed from `nums` before the recursion, then the M is almost eliminated from O() of the whole algorithm. In that case, time complexity becomes O(M+N*2<sup>N</sup>), where for reasonable M, s.t. M <= N*2<sup>N</sup>, the M can be dropped from the expression.